# chattr command is not setting flag

Tags: ubuntu, unix

I have connected to a ubuntu system using ssh terminal.
when I issue the following command I get the error

```
chattr -R -i Audit
chattr: Operation not permitted while setting flags on Audit
```

This happened because I have applied the following command while a script was running and saving files into the folder Audit

```
chattr -R +i Audit
```

Is there a quick workaround?. I don't want to run fsck as this is a critical system.

```
 Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-119-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution

```
sudo chattr -R -i Audit
```

This has unsetted the flag i on folder Audit recursively

Comment: Please note that question was about `how to +i` it but your answer is that `you have succeeded to -i` it instead (:

+i and -i